# Incompatible JavaHL library loaded. Subversion 1.8.x required not going away

Tags: eclipse, svn, javahl

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and i have the following subclipse/JavaHL installation on eclipse Mars.
[image]

And this seems on line with this http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

i have 1.10.xx subclipse version for a 1.8.xx javaHl version. Yet on every  Eclipse Mars startup i keep getting the error message and when i see the eclipse team->svn>svn Interface tab i see this 
[image]

So right now i am using SVNKit instead. Any idea on what is causing this. And for your information, i have an eclipse neon that's running fine using [image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after trying a lot of things that did not work, i finally managed to solve it by updating the javaHL native Library Adapter to 1.9. I did not know where to get it from so i tried the eclipse marketplace .
**Help --> Eclipse Marketplace --> Installed tab --> Subclipse --> Update** (click on the ltlle arrow in the button if install is showed to select it) then make sure the javaHl adapter is checked and update.